# Overriding a template from block

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, overrides, third-party-module

I am currently trying to override a register.phml from a custom module in my own custom module.

My modules name is `UV_Mitgliedsnummer`, the custom module I want to override the template from is `Clarion_CustomAttribute`.

> magento/app/code/UV/Mitgliedsnummer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Form\Register" />
    </config>
```

> magento/app/code/UV/Mitgliedsnummer/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="UV_Mitgliedsnummer" setup_version="1.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Clarion_CustomAttribute" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> magento/app/code/UV/Mitgliedsnummer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" as="virtual" template="form/register.phtml">

<!--
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="clarion.register">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Clarion_CustomAttribute::view.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
-->
```

> magento/app/code/UV/Mitgliedsnummer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

```
Ich bin ein Test. :-)
```

Do you have any suggestions why it is not working?
Thanks :-)

Edit: It seems to work now but I get these exceptions.

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Ungültiger Block-Typ: Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register

Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Vendor\Module\Block\Form\Register does not exist
```

Comment: in layout file  try changing `template="form/register.phtml"` to `template="UV_Mitgliedsnummer::form/register.phtml"`

Comment: You have not added Block file with class you have defined for your template in xml Or you have assigned wrong class name in xml

Comment: Sorry I am new to Magento. Can you describe more detailled and which files you mean? Thanks so far !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code in xml file to override template

```
<referenceBlock name="block-name">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UV_Mitgliedsnummer::form/register.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Note:** *Change "block-name" as per your modules layout structure*

Comment: How can I find the block name? Clarion_CustomAttributes is a custom module. When I turn dev mode on, it shows me this as block: Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register

Comment: it will be there in the `Clarion_CustomAttribute` module's xml file which your are overriding

Comment: <code> <?xml version="1.0"?>

<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UV_Mitgliedsnummer::form/register.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock> </code> doesn't work :-/

Comment: The module xml I am overriding is overriding some module too. It is also referencing to "customer_form_register". May that be the problem?

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Clarion_CustomerAttribute::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>